# Blob url in internet explorer with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, angularjs, bloburls

Given this code (from someone else):

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);

module.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope){
    $scope.json = JSON.stringify({a:1, b:2});
});

module.directive('myDownload', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{ data: '=' },
        link:function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            function getUrl(){
                return URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([JSON.stringify(scope.data)], {type: "application/json"}));
            }

            elm.append($compile(
                    '<a class="btn" download="backup.json"' +
                    'href="' + getUrl() + '">' +
                    'Download' +
                    '</a>'
            )(scope));                    

            scope.$watch(scope.data, function(){
                elm.children()[0].href = getUrl();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

[The fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BrPRz/1/) works fine to download in chrome.  But clicking the 'download' link does nothing in IE11.  No error, no warning, no response at all.

But according to [this](http://caniuse.com/bloburls) it's supported in IE10 and 11.

Is there some IE security setting that needs to be changed or what is going on?

Comment: IE does not support all blob mime-types, did you try making it just plain text and see if that works?

Comment: I have the same problem, and I've tried it with `text/plain`, to no avail. Interestingly, I can right-click, save target as, and that works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found a solution for this.  First, IE handles blob saving differently, specifically it uses:

```
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(new Blob([element], {type:"text/plain"}), "filename.txt");`
```

If you look at the source code for [this page](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/BlobBuilder/), you will see how they do it.

But to get this to work with cross browser support is a pain.. and a the end of the day you will end up [with FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/).

..which is what I ended up using, and works like a charm.

Comment: I can conform this works. I have the following if condition for IE / ROW:

    `// IE 10 / 11
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
    } else {
      ...`

Comment: Nice find.  I was about to drive myself crazy looking at browser comparison charts.

Answer (score 1):

Use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)! So easy to use.

**For PDF sent as binary response:**

```
// In HTML, first include filesaver.js with <script src="/scripts/filesaver.js"></script>

var thisPDFfileName = 'my.pdf';
var fileData = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });

// Cross-browser using FileSaver.js
saveAs(fileData, thisPDFfileName);
```

**For NPM version:**

```
var fileSaver = require('file-saver');

var thisPDFfileName = 'my.pdf';
var fileData = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });

// Cross-browser using FileSaver.js
fileSaver.saveAs(fileData, thisPDFfileName);
```

Works like a charm, cross-browser.

Thanks to @Nicros for pointing filesaver.js out in his answer. I made this answer so users can quickly copy and paste an example of it, who don't want to use MS specific code. (Cross-browser rocks)