# Open links made by createObjectURL in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, blob

Why can't you open the link in the following demo:
http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html

You cannot even right click and open it in a new tab/window. Is there any setting in the browser I need to customize?

Comment: Maybe the download attribute used on the a tag is not supported. http://status.modern.ie/adownloadattribute

Comment: The `download` attribute isn't supported in IE and Safari. But I'm not going to download/save the link: as mentioned in my question title it doesn't even open/navigate to the link. Safari works as expected. Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mori/yv7DG/) without the download attribute.

Comment: Did you have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533980/blob-url-in-internet-explorer-with-angularjs)? Looks like the same problem.

Answer (score 121):

This demo uses Blob URL which is not supported by IE due to security restrictions.

IE has its own API for creating and downloading files, which is called `msSaveOrOpenBlob`.

Here is my cross-browser solution that works on IE, Chrome and Firefox:

```js
function createDownloadLink(anchorSelector, str, fileName){
    if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        var fileData = [str];
        blobObject = new Blob(fileData);
        $(anchorSelector).click(function(){
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, fileName);
        });
    } else {
        var url = "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(str);
        $(anchorSelector).attr("download", fileName);
        $(anchorSelector).attr("href", url);
    }
}

$(function () {
    var str = "hi,file";
    createDownloadLink("#export", str, "file.txt");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="export" class="myButton" download="" href="#">export</a>
```

Comment: Seems like it doesnt work within a web worker:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928992/download-blob-from-webworker-in-ie11

Comment: I really hoped the time of "if stupid internet explorer then" would be over. Thank you for your submission, it helped me a lot.

Comment: this solution works in Edge too. I was trying to download a browser audio recoding, worked like a charm!

Comment: Not working for me either in IE 11, any thing I might need to change, settings etc?

Comment: JS Fiddle recently changed its website to show the result inside iframe. The IE part doesn't work in an iframe. If you try this code in a regular page, it works in IE 11 too.

Comment: What do we do then if we want to embed the pdf into the page?

Comment: @robert.bo.roth Do you want to generate PDF on the client side or is the PDF already on server? If it is already on server, I recommend PDF.JS(http://stackoverflow.com/a/291823/1439313). For client-side pdf generation(on the fly), use jsPDF(https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)

Comment: The PDF is already on the server, but due to security reasons, we don't have web-accessible links to these PDFs. In order to preview content in our application, we send the base64 data to render in the browser with the <object> tag. It works for images and PDFs in other browsers.

Comment: @robert.bo.roth Unfortunately, IE has no support for inline PDFs. The only way is to show a download link to user. PDFObject(https://pdfobject.com/) can detect browser support and switch between inline PDF and download link.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just gonna go with msSaveOrOpenBlob function, and then let the user decide whether to Open or Save it. Technically I have a distnict "Save/Download" link separately to my "Preview" link, but this will work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: this works with angular2+spring boot rest controller but in angular1+spring boot rest controller it not works...

Answer (score 45):

Here is the function for downloading any file as blob. (tested on IE and Non-IE)

```
var download_csv_using_blob = function (file_name, content) {
    var csvData = new Blob([content], { type: 'text/csv' });
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) { // for IE
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(csvData, file_name);
    } else { // for Non-IE (chrome, firefox etc.)
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = "display: none";
        var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(csvData);
        a.href =  csvUrl;
        a.download = file_name;
        a.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href)
        a.remove();
    }
};
```

Note: Please change the type of your file, if needed.

Comment: There's no need to actually append the element to the body, so setting the `style` and calling `remove()` are also unnecessary. Tested this on Chrome, FF, and Edge Chromium.

Answer (score 3):

If the data is coming from Ajax then you can add

```
if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)
 xhttp.responseType = "arraybuffer";
else
 xhttpGetPack.responseType = "blob";
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style.display = "none";

// IE
if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)
{
  a.onclick = ((evx) => 
  {
      var newBlob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(xhttpGetPack.response)]);
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob, "myfile.ts");
  });
  a.click();
}
else //Chrome and safari
{
  var file = URL.createObjectURL(xhttpGetPack.response);
  a.href = file;
  a["download"] = "myFile.ts";
  a.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        //File Object return in ajax Success in data variable
         var blob = new Blob([data]);
         if (navigator.appVersion.toString().indexOf('.NET') > 0) //For IE
          {
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, "filename.ext");
          }
          else if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') >-1) 
              {
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = "filename.ext";
                document.body.appendChild(link);//For FireFox <a> tag event 
                //not working
                link.click();
            }
          else
          {
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = "filename.ext" 
                link.click();
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

For inside iframe download in Internet Explorer 11, you need to use `parent.window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, "filename.ext");`.