# Download Blob from webworker in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, web-worker

I m trying to download a **large** blob from a web worker.

With Firefox and Chrome it's quite simple:

```
url = URL.createObjectURL(oMyBlob);
//Then i return the url to the main thread and go to it
```

But according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007073/open-links-made-by-createobjecturl-in-ie11) IE doesn't allow that, and we must use this:

```
navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, defaultName);
```

**But *navigator* seems to not have access to *msSaveBlob* within a webworker...**

What's the best way then to download a Blob (~100MB) within an IE11 worker?

Comment: Do you have a solution for this ? By web worker do you mean an ASP application hosted in IIS ?

Comment: No i mean Javascript web worker. And i still have no solution for that.

Comment: Thanks for useful info, found a question related to this with answer, hope it works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354491/reading-an-object-url-produced-in-a-worker-with-ie