# reading an object URL produced in a worker with IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web-worker

I have a webworker that is producing a CSV for downloading, and to conserve memory I only have it return the URL it produces from teh blob..
My worker code looks something like::

```
var blob = new Blob([ResultOfSomeWork()],{type:'text/csv'});
URL.createObjectURL(blob);
self.postMessage({url:blob.url});
```

My goal is to just be able to download it in firefox and chrome this is very easy as I can just set up an invisible `<a>` and have it be clicked to download it.

For IE10 I want to use `msSaveBlob` but I need a blob which I don't want to transfer.
How can I download a object dataurl in IE10?

Comment: What type of data is produced by `ResultOfSomeWork()`? If its an ArrayBuffer you can transfer it via `postMessage` without it being copied.

Comment: It is a `string`. It's just a large csv.

Answer (score 2):

So I found a solution that works. Apparently, I can XHR and read the content back in my main thread.

```
worker.onmessage = function(event){
    var url = event.data.url;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType='blob';
    xhr.onload = function(){
       msSaveBlob(xhr.response, fileName +'.csv');
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

While this feels extremely complicated it works well in practice and is really fast.