# Saving a JSON object as a file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I wanted to know if there was any way to save a JSON object as a .json file in the project directory. I have a form and each time a user fills it, I want the JSON file to be appended. I'm currently using AngularJS only.

Comment: JSON is a string ... not an object ... so, it should be easier knowing this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downloading file from ajax result using blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29393601/downloading-file-from-ajax-result-using-blob)

Comment: If you want to programmatically write a file to the disc (not download), it's next to impossible for security reasons. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript

Comment: Simply anwser, you can't save files server side using `JavaScript` only. You gotta need some server side language aswell, like `PHP`.

Comment: ...or Javascript. But server-side.

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS is just JavaScript, so use any methods that let you save files with JS (*it's better to do it with backend like PHP*). One of such methods is `FileSaver.js` (uses HTML5 features).

Here is a working demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myJSON = {
    "A": "B"
  };

  $scope.saveJSON = function(json) {
    var jsonse = JSON.stringify(json);
    var blob = new Blob([jsonse], {
      type: "application/json"
    });
    $scope.filename = $scope.filename || "my_json";
    saveAs(blob, $scope.filename + ".json");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  Some JSON:
  <pre>
    {{myJSON | json}}
  </pre>
  File Name: <input type="text" ng-model="filename" /><br>
  <button ng-click="saveJSON(myJSON)">Save</button>

</div>
```

OR you can send a request to the backend like PHP with

```
$http.post("createJSON.php",json).then((res)=>{...}, (err)=>{...})
```

And receive with:

```
<?php
$dataReceived = file_get_contents('php://input');
$myFile = json_decode( $dataReceived );

$path = $myFile->path; // path to store it in
$name = $myFile->name; // file name
$JSON = $myFile->json; // content

# Storing file
$file = fopen($path.$name.".json", 'w');
fwrite($file, $JSON);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: I tried your snippet, it's not saving a file to the disk, it's downloading a JSON file. Not sure that's what OP wants

Comment: @JeremyThille the question is "_save a JSON object as a .json file_". My code does exactly that.

Comment: What it doesn't do is `each time a user fills it, I want the JSON file to be appended in the project directory`.

Comment: @JeremyThille which is outside of the **question's** scope. For that, this can be flagged as "too broad". My answer is just an example of how a file can be saved, feel free to expand it with other specifications

Comment: I fail to see how it's outside of the question's scope, given I have quoted the original question.

Comment: Actually, what I wanted was exactly what @JeremyThille has in mind. Is there any way to pull it off?

Comment: Not with server-side JS, no. Browsers don't allow JS to freely access the local filesystem for obvious security reasons. You have to use a server.

Answer (score 0):

you can't save files to the disk just with javascript. maybe you really need nodejs,and use the fs module.
[Is it possible to write data to file using only JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript)