# Opening PDF file in new tab angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf

I tried opening a PDF file using the `window.open()`, but the window opens and closes automatically and the file is downloaded like any other file. How to make the pdf file open in new tab? There are no ad blockers installed.

Comment: have you tried using `window.open('filename','_blank');`

Comment: Yes, that's the function I am using now. Only thing is I am getting the data directly from backend and not local file

Comment: yes, NP, have you tried this method? with `_blank`?

Comment: Yes, the window just opens and closes immediately in chrome

Comment: Check value of `Content-Disposition` header. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-do-i-force-files-to-open-in-the-browser-instead-of-downloading-pdf

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example, please? Otherwise it's difficult to find issues.

Comment: I am using window.open(fileURL, '_blank');

Answer (score 53, accepted):

From @barbsan idea, I changed the http headers and received a blob and used that to display the blob as pdf using window.open(). It worked.

Here is my sample code.

In service file

```
downloadPDF(url): any {
    const options = { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob  };
    return this.http.get(url, options).map(
    (res) => {
        return new Blob([res.blob()], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    });
  }
```

In component file

```
this.dataService.downloadPDF(url).subscribe(res => {
  const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(res);
  window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
});
```

Comment: Be careful if you're using an ad-blocker extension. Ad-blockers block blob URLs by default. As a result, e.g. in Chrome and Firefox, with the uBlock Origin extension, it would try to open the new window and close it automatically. You can read more about here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51272781/why-do-ad-blockers-block-blobs

Comment: Also, if you care about this working in IE too, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007073/open-links-made-by-createobjecturl-in-ie11

Comment: How to set file name while opening file in new tab with above approach?

Comment: any idea how to set name of new tab when opening the PDF?

Comment: can any one provide make a file name  opening file in new tab with above approach

Comment: Does this require the PDF to be publicly available? E.g. without authorization?

Answer (score 14):

One liner solution to open a pdf file in new tab. You just need to have file url and use this function on button click.

`window.open(url, '_blank');`

Answer (score 1):

you can display pdf fle in new tab by the line:

```
window.open(fileUrl, '_blank');
```

The fileUrl is a variable that contains the file path.

Answer (score 1):

For the Angular 13 version

```
downloadPDF(url: string): Observable<Blob> {
   const options = { responseType: 'blob' as 'json' };
   return this.httpClient
  .get<Blob>(url, options)
  .pipe(map(res => new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' })));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need user the "**target="_blank**" in the tag ;

exemple:   `<a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/"> </a>`

Comment: Hi Hoiama, welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your answer doesn't address the original question, which was to use explicitly `window.open()`. Please make sure to read the question and any answers thoroughly, because it's easy to miss something like this!

Answer (score 0):

How to make it work in Angular 10, changes just a little bit, this in the service file from @K Harish answer

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


    return this.http.get(url, options).pipe(map(
    (res) => {
        return new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    }));
```