# How to use DOM click() in Angular using Renderer2

Tags: angular, elementref, angular-renderer2

I have a method that gets invoked based on certain user action. In that method I am trying to download a file using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23013574/7605162).

But I don't want to use/refer `document` object directly so I am using combination of `Renderer2` and `ElementRef`. This is snapshot of code:

```js
const link = this.renderer.createElement('a');
this.renderer.setAttribute(link, 'download', requiredFile.name);
this.renderer.setAttribute(link, 'href', requiredFile.url);
this.renderer.setAttribute(link, 'target', '_blank');
this.renderer.appendChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement, link);
// how to achieve link.click() here?
this.renderer.removeChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement, link);
```

I need some help to figure out how to invoke DOM `click()` method here using `Renderer2` and `ElementRef`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening PDF file in new tab angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204276/opening-pdf-file-in-new-tab-angular-4)

Comment: Why does link.click() not work here..?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are two methods to register an event on a DOM element. The first one is with vanilla JavaScript and the second one with rxjs operators.

**Method 1**

```
fromEvent(link, 'click', () => console.log('do something here')).subscribe() // don't forget to unsubscribe
```

**Method 2**

```js
link.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('clicked 2'))
```

I remember that it was discouraged to use the second method in combination with Render. This is not the case anymore though

**Method 3**

```
this.renderer.listen(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
   console.log('Clicked')
})
```

**Dispatch click event automatically**

1)

```
const clickEvent = new Event('click')
this.elementRef.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent)
```

2. 

Like @MikeOne wrote in the comments

```
link.click()
```

Comment: I think above two solution work when user manually click the element. I want click() to happen automatically.

Comment: @KinleyChristian I updated my answer. It seems that it's not crystal clear what you are trying to achieve. The `link.click()` it does the trick. What is stopping you from using it?