# Apexcharts in WPF webbrowser control "access is denied" when downloading svg blob

Tags: javascript, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control, apexcharts

I am trying to run Apexcharts.js in a WPF webBrowser. The chart processing is exactly what I wanted, but downloading svg produces a Javascript "Access is Denied". I am not able to access the browser debugging tools and have speculated that it is to do with the DOM but to no avail and the error char location is in the middle of a function (after a "document.body.appendChild(i)" call) but I think this may be barking up the wrong tree. Have used the cdn and a local copy and run the file in a standard browser which worked perfectly. I have put content into the control both as a physical file and a NavigateToString.

Comment: This looks interesting [Open links made by createObjectURL in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007073/open-links-made-by-createobjecturl-in-ie11)

Comment: Would appear that Edge as as webbrowser control does not like blobs....